# How to embed file browser into the Blender addon interface

Tags: python, interface, add-on, customization, file-browser

I'm trying to find a way to display the items in the target folder in the addon interface, i.e. like in the Blender file browser:

[image]

I tried to make a text picture for an example:

```
|     File Browser     |
|- Folder_1            |
|--> Folder_2          |
|----> File_1          |
|----> File_2          |
|--> Folder_3          |
|----> File_3          |
|______________________|
```

Tell me please, what extensions use this solution or what solves this task in Blender?

I looking for this solution to decide this [issue](https://gitlab.com/cadbase/cadbaselibrary-blender/-/issues/4) (link to GitLab).
And I apologize if the answer was on the surface, but I didn't find it.

Comment: There is no treelist widgets in Blender. You will have to improvise. Like that: https://blenderartists.org/t/blender-treelist-expanding-subelements-ui/1191260

Comment: Thank you! Got it. I'll give it a try and let you know how the result is :)